# How to add active class to tab's dynamically created navigation using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm attempting to add an active class to an element for tabs navigation using vue.js. The problem is, besides being new to Vue, the navigation items are dynamically created in a for loop as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${tabnav.tabs}" var="tab" varStatus="loop">
  <c:if test="${loop.count le tabnav.totalTabs}">
    <li v-bind:class="{active : isActive}" v-on:click="tabSelected = ${loop.count}; isActive = !isActive">${tab.heading}</li>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

the JS looks like this:

```
Vue.component('tabnav', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            tabSelected: 1,
            isActive: false
        };
    }
});
```

The problem is that this is toggling the class on ALL the items in the navigation rather than the one that was clicked.

Do I need to create a method for handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `isActive`. Check to see if the `tabSelected` is equal to the current tab in the loop.

```
v-bind:class="{active : tabSelected === ${loop.count}}"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Is there anything about this in Vue documentation? Or is this just general knowledge after building Vue skills?

Comment: @lscmaro Well, for this in particular, its not really a Vue thing. If you set `active` based off a global value, then all the tabs will be active when it is set. So you were part way there by storing the currently selected tab in data; you just needed to complete the loop and activate only the tab that is equal to the selected tab, which in your case is identified by `loop.count`.

Comment: That makes sense. Great explanation.