# How to make select dropdown a second navigation and work with tabs using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a tabs with navigaion setup using Vue that is working just fine thanks to a previous question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331462/how-to-add-active-class-to-tabs-dynamically-created-navigation-using-vue-js). The code for the tabs navigation looks like this:

```
<ul>
<c:forEach items="${tabnav.tabs}" var="tab" varStatus="loop">
  <c:if test="${loop.count le tabnav.totalTabs}">
  <li v-bind:class="{active : tabSelected = ${loop.count}}" v-on:click="tabSelected = 
  ${loop.count}">${tab.heading}</li>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

My goal is to have 2 navigation for the tabs content area. The dynamically created `<li>` for desktop and a `<select>` dropdown for mobile.

I seem to be having issues with the select and it will not change the tabs and the 2 navigations are not in sync with each other. Meaning if I were to change the visible tab using the desktop `li` nav, the mobile `select` option should keep the correct active tab content area/option vice verse.

My Code for the select is this:

```
<select>
<c:forEach items="${tabnav.tabs}" var="tab" varStatus="loop">
 <c:if test="${loop.count le tabnav.totalTabs}">
  <option v-on:change="tabSelected = ${loop.count}">${tab.heading}</option>
 </c:if>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Do I need to create a method in Vue for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `v-model.number` on the select.

```
<select v-model.number="tabSelected">
<c:forEach items="${tabnav.tabs}" var="tab" varStatus="loop">
 <c:if test="${loop.count le tabnav.totalTabs}">
  <option value="${loop.count}">${tab.heading}</option>
 </c:if>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Here's the documentation for [binding a select](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) in Vue.

Based on comments, the `number` modifier was added to make sure the model value is numeric.

Comment: This almost works. When I add the `v-model` and click on the desktop nav it works and is in sync, but when I go to mobile and select it sets all the tabs to `display:none` .. Any thoughts?

Comment: @lscmaro might try `v-model.number`. What is the rendered output on the page? Use View Source. Here is an example of how I would expect it to look. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/JrKEdN?editors=1010

Comment: That did it. I assume that error was due to string vs int conflicts? I'll add that update to your answer for future references too. Thanks!

Comment: Yep! That is the exact output in my source from your codepen.

Comment: @lscmaro Just one more clarification, the reason the `number` modifier is required is because of the triple equals here `v-bind:class="{active : tabSelected === 1}"`. Were that a double equal, the number modifier would not be required. Triple equal is *exact* match, where double equal allows type conversions.

Comment: Ahhh .. Yep .. makes sense. Good eye! Also, I'm thinking they use `===` in Vue itself for the tabs and that could be the reason for the `number` modifier too... not 100 on that though, but I think it's a fair assumption.